# Function with too many arguments. How to use and call object literals as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ecmascript-6, object-literal

I have a function in which appends elements to a page. This function is called at multiple places so I have parameters set up for the classNames as the styling is done by bootstrap.

Since I am calling the function multiple times, filling in values for the parameters can get confusing and leaves it open for mistakes.

I was looking to use an `object literal` in place. I am not sure about how to go about this and don't know how to call such a function.

My function:

```
const my_func = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g = true) => {
$(a).append(`
<div class='${b}'>${f}</div>
<input class='${b}'> />
<button class='${c}'></button>
if(g) {
  .....
}
`);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty similar to what you've got already, except the function declaration would be `const my_func = ({a,b,c,d,e,f})=> { /* ... */};` and when calling the function you can do `my_func({a:aVal, b:bVal})` and so forth. You can also use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in the function declaration if you need it.

Comment: @David784, doesn't that make it just a confusing and just as long?

Comment: The main benefit of using an object over positional arguments is that order doesn't matter.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner, aaah makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For organizing your function **you can simply [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your input parameters with the basic assignment**, then whenever you call it you can specify each pair of the input parameter and its value by a colon (`:`).

But keep in mind you should always separate the logic part and string part in order to make things clear and easier to read.

So I just modified your code a bit and passing some dummy values into it.

```js
const my_func = ({
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e,
  f,
  g = true
}) => {
  let html = `<div class='${b}'>${f}</div>
              <input class='${b}'/>
              <button class='${c}'>${d}</button>`;

  if (g) {
    html += '<div>g is true</div>'
  }

  $(a).append(html);
}

const container = $(".container");
my_func({a: container, b: "red", c: "bold", d: "submit", f: "this is a division", g: true}); //I didn't pass e parameter to it and simply skipped it.
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const my_func = ({ a, b, c, d, e, f, g = true }) => {
  $(a).append(`<div class='${b}'>${f}</div>`);
  $(a).sppend(`<input class='${b}' />`);
  $(a).sppend(`<button class='${c}'></button>`);
  if (g) {
    // do something
  }
}

my_func({ a: '', b: '', c: '', d: '', e: '', f: '', g: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) will extract all the properties you know you need to variables to use later. This also makes it clear what properties you are planning on using from the object argument, and allows specifying default values (which is a lot harder, but possible, without destructuring).

```js
// this example clearly shows what options the function accepts,
// and describes the function behavior without having to read any of the function body
function findText(query, {caseInsensitive = true, fuzziness = 1, maxMatches}){…}
```

But you don't have to destructure. If you don't really care to specify exactly what you need from the object (say you were passing the object to other functions or such), then just accept the object as the function parameter and reference the properties as needed.

```js
// this function accepts an object (`calendar'), but cares more about its
// role than its contents
function saveAppointment(title, date, calendar=getDefaultCalendar()){…}
```

Sometimes this is better, depending on intent. If your object represents function options that effect how the function behaves, destructuring is generally the clearest. But if the object is some sort of data or rich object (especially if the object has methods), then you probably wouldn't restructure it. It depends on if you intend the object to be more "transparent" or opaque - is the function interested in the inside of the object, or does it need to collaborate with the object in more of a ["tell, don't ask"](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) style.